# Is this code an efficient implementation of Reservoir Sampling?

Tags: java, random

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12679544/1075247) an answer this to a question about drawing a random line from a file too large to put into memory. I hacked the below code together. In essence, this is what Reservoir Sampling does, in pseudo-code:

```
Scan over the 'tape'
    Put the first 'n' samples in a reservoir(of size n)
    // samples are lines of a document, numbers, whatever
    After the first 'n' :
        Pick a random number between 1 and NumberOfLinesCounted
        if the number is between 1 and n
            replace an existing line with a 1/n chance
```

Here is the code designed to scan over a document, with said sampling method:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class reservoirSampling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Sampler mySampler = new Sampler();
        List<String> myList = mySampler.sampler(10);
        for(int index = 0;index<myList.size();index++){
            System.out.println(myList.get(index));
        }
    }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sampler {

    public Sampler(){}
    public List<String> sampler (int reservoirSize) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String currentLine=null;
        //reservoirList is where our selected lines stored
        List <String> reservoirList= new ArrayList<String>(reservoirSize); 
        // we will use this counter to count the current line number while iterating
        int count=0; 

        Random ra = new Random();
        int randomNumber = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Open_source.html")).useDelimiter("\n");
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            currentLine = sc.next();
            count ++;
            if (count<=reservoirSize)
            {
                reservoirList.add(currentLine);
            }
            else if ((randomNumber = (int) ra.nextInt(count))<reservoirSize)
            {
                reservoirList.set(randomNumber, currentLine);
            }
        }
        return reservoirList;
    }
}
```

I'm using something very similar on a project I am on at the moment (i.e. the code is close enough I can transfer any changes easily by hand).

Is this a) efficient, and b) actually reservoir sampling (with equal odds of any line being drawn)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reviving an old, but really interesting post, that did not get a great opportunity for review the first time around....

### What you've done well:

This code, for the most part, is excellent. As for your specific questions:

Is this:

1. efficient

   Mostly, yes. The inefficiencies in here are all related to the IO, and the Scanner, not your code. A more low-level API may net you some performance benefits, but not likely. You are also (re)using the Random class well, and there should not be a problem there.
2. actually reservoir sampling (with equal odds of any line being drawn)?

   Yes. This is a good implementation of the reservoir algorithm. The random arguments are good, and the substitutions should be fine.

### What's concerning

- The most significant beef is that you do not close the `Scanner`. Scanners can hold on to open file-handles, and, if the file really is big, this may have system-wide consequences. A try-catch-finally block would be appropriate (or, a try-with-resources if you're on Java7 now).
- A second (smaller) issue is that reservoir sampling is designed to handle huge data in a streaming way. I know it is perhaps unrealistic to consider in your use-case, but multi-gigabyte files are not unexpected, and the likelihood of overflowing the `count` variable is not unrealistic. That would cause problems....
- You should consider converting `count` and `randomNumber` to be `long` values, and only convert it back to an `int` if it is less-than `reservoirSize`

### Finally....

Nice code to review. Thanks. Obviously, the new language features in more recent Java versions may be interesting to consider....

Answer (score 6):

A few random notes:

1. `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`. Declaring both `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` is redundant.
2. The `Sampler()` constructor can be omitted, since it is just the default constructor that would have been implicitly defined anyway.
3. Your `sampler()` method is just a pure function, and could be made `static`.
4. The `reservoirSampling` class should be named `ReservoirSampling`:

   > Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

   Reference: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language, 9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)
5. According to the previous Code Conventions, `sampler()` should be named `sample()`:

   > Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
6. It is a bad idea to hard-code the filename from which you will be sampling. The file should be passed in as a parameter.  I think it's odd to take samples from an HTML file, which usually doesn't contain line-oriented data.
7. Variables `currentLine` and `randomNumber` are only used inside the while loop, and should be declared inside it.  (See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
8. It is not too difficult to change your code produce samples with *any* type, not just strings:

   ```
   public static <T> List<T> sample(Iterator<T> pool, int reservoirSize)
   {
       //reservoirList is where our selected lines stored
       List<T> reservoirList = new ArrayList<T>(reservoirSize);
       // we will use this counter to count the current item number while iterating        
       int count = 0;

       Random ra = new Random();
       while (pool.hasNext())
       {
           T current = pool.next();
           count++;
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   (See *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 27: Favor generic methods*)
9. For an `Iterator<String>` over the lines of a file, you could use `FileUtils.lineIterator(new File(...))` from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#lineIterator%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 2):

At the first glance

You can use `Scanner.netxLine()` available on all OS.

```
(randomNumber = (int) ra.nextInt(count))<reservoirSize
```

*EDIT  suppressed unnecessary lines after comments*

Comment: So use sc.nextLine() not Scanner(...).useDelimeter("\n")? Got it. Also, I don't follow how an `else if` would miss some lines? Reservoir sampling takes the first `n` lines then randomly swaps them out. Sometimes it swaps, sometimes it doesn't I thnk I see what you're doing, but that's not quite the point of reservoir sampling I don't think.

Comment: @Pureferret `else if` whithout a final `else` block do not catch all conditions. But it is that you want. So remove `while(1) ..` line and `break` line with a `}` so you remove the negative int randomised and avoid a Exception (no negative integer in an array position)

Comment: Well the only thing not inside both the `else` and the `if` statement is the while and the random number, which the iff relies on - why not make them the same line? Also, I should never get a random number less than 0....

Comment: @Pureferret `java.util.Random` return also negative number so you cannot test the two limits in the `if( ..)` statement . Maodify with EDIT

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)`nextInt(int n): Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.` So no. It can't return a negative.

Comment: @Pureferret - Exact, as I usually use `.nextInt()` so my response out of scope. Corrected